# location.href only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook

[Edit: ok, my bad. The redirect works, it's an error in app.php that immediately redirects back to index.php. Thanks for your help though :) ]

So I'm building this Facebook-app where, after a bunch of steps, you're redirected (inside an iframe) to a PHP file named app.php. This redirect is done using JS:

```
// this is in 'join-app.js':
location.href = "app.php?userid=" + userdata.id;
```

This bit of JS is in a seperate .js-file (join-app.js) which is loaded into index.php:

```
<!-- this is in 'index.php': -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/join-app.js"></script>
```

index.php is the source of the iframe on Facebook.

The above works fine in Chrome on OS X, but for some reason it does not work in Safari on OS X, or IE on Windows. It does work on Firefox on OS X and Windows... In IE and Safari, the index.php page just keeps getting reloaded.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or something? Or it just does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For redirects in JavaScript, it is usual to use `window.location`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
   //-->
</script>
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as the answer if this question is solved, so this question will be closed.